# sublime text beatyfind code, emmet way

Tags: sublimetext, emmet

Guys sorry for my bad english , i am using emmet on sublime text, and all my code is very ordered, but sometimes i must paste external code with other oder , is there any way for order this new code like maked on emmet? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forward numbering is like this:

```
ul>li{$}*4
```

Backward numbering like this:

```
ul>li{$@-}*4
```

It results in:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

If you have your own numbered list of any length, you can just highlight your whole list, go to the Koan line at the bottom (make sure you are in Koan mode - ctrl alt enter) and type whatever your wrapping should be (like ul>li* in our example - note: you have to leave off the "4", since your list has an unspecified number of lines, and also the curly brackets and the $ sign, since you are not using any automatic number system; so just end with the asterix).

Example:

```
34
324
12
1
453
9
```

will result in

```
<ul>
  <li>34</li>
  <li>324</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>453</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

when you type

ul>li* into the Koan line.